# Post thumbnail throwing size limit parameters in <img>

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

```
<ul class="widget_image_2">
  <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
  <li>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium'); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), $number_of_words ); ?></a>
  </li>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
```

the above code is generating this in the browser:

```
    <img width="300" src="http://........./wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bitcoin_1-300x200.jpg" 
    class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="" 
        srcset="http://......../wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bitcoin_1-300x200.jpg 300w, 
http://blewspaper.blogeto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bitcoin_1-768x512.jpg 768w, 
http://.........../wp-content/uploads/2017/11/bitcoin_1-1024x683.jpg 1024w" 
sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

But these two are not allowing the images to take full width in the responsive version(600px):

```
sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"
width="300"
```

Is there a method to get rid of this?

I also checked CSS there is nothing written in the CSS to impose such limitations.

Comment: Let me re-check it and then update you.

Comment: I could not find any CSS for the said class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need to set the `width`, `object-fit` o similar CSS properties for the images you want to take the full width of its container. Otherwise, the images have the width they have. Anyway, I'm not sure if I get your point. Do you have another image size for 600px that should be included in the `sizes` or `srcset` attributes?

Comment: You mean [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/). I am going to try it with the custom size image.

Comment: There are several CSS properties that can be used, `width` and `object-fit` are just two. I can not know which one you need, but your problem seems to be related with CSS and not with the HTML markup you get from WordPress. The `width="300"` attribute for a image 300px wide is correct and it does not limit how it can be displayed

Comment: @cybmeta Creating a custom thumbnail option fixed my issue.

Comment: Yes, that too, but it is not the problem you was talking about. You specifically said you didn't want to create another custom thumbnail :) but to have the current one be 100% wide, and that is a pure CSS issue. Anyway, glad you fix your problem.

Comment: Yes initially didn't want to, but for the moment it was like what I initially wanted was not manifesting so chosen the alternative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change image size `medium` to `large` e.g `the_post_thumbnail( 'large' )`. If you enlarge `300px` image to `600px` your image will be distorted. Or if you need more control on image size then you have to register a new image size using [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

Comment: Its not about distortion. distortion is another aspect if that were the case I could have changed to large, but the thing is because of that restriction the <img> is not taking maximum available space. large is not always good for optimization unless there is a really necessity for such a big image. I know how to create custom sizes, but its not about size but restrictions thrown.

Comment: Then it can be resolved using CSS. Just use `.wp-post-image { width: 100%; max-width:100% }`. Btw scaling a `300px` width image to `600px`  maybe good for optimization according to you, but that's not a good UX.

Comment: I understand your suggestion and I appreciate you for all your help, but you are not getting my point.

Comment: `add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180, true ); ` can 180 be replaced by auto?

Comment: You are defining a hard crop size here, WordPress will create a `custom-size` image with `220x180` dimension. What do mean "replaced by auto"? Whenever you display `custom-size` image with `the_post_thumbnail()` function WP will add the `width` attribute. But if you're thinking about removing the attribute then this might help you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-width-and-height-attributes-from-inserted-images/

Comment: in the WP backend, we have this [feature](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflowfiles/_wp_backen.png) in a sense it uses height auto so in this → `add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180, true ); ` is 180 the max-possible height?

Comment: If you set hard crop to `true` in your case it is `true` then the image height will be exact `180px`. To understand cropping factors please check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#description

Comment: Your suggestion to create custom size solved my issue. so I upvoted + accepted. You are new here, but doing great. How much experience do you have in WP/PHP? Can you suggest me how can I also become good in PHP? any list of the recommended programme that I should try building.

Comment: Thanks. Good to hear that my suggestion worked for you. I have 3 years of experience in WP and PHP. But I'm fluent in WP API than raw PHP. To become good in PHP I'd suggest you to focus on one topic and learn as much as you can then create something useful using what you learned. For instance, if you focus on string manipulation then learn whatever you can on string manipulation related to PHP and after completing the initial learning create something useful, maybe an extensive string manipulation library.

Comment: I have 7-10 months experience when I started learning all this. so quiet behind than many.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll learn quickly. Focus and keep up the hard work.